# Android WidgetPreview Error on API 26 Emulator

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I am trying to create a widget preview with the WidgetPreview app on a API 26 emulator, but it shows "Error saving preview" as a toast message. It works on API level 21.
There are zero results online. Anyone have an idea what could cause this?

Comment: Does that app log anything useful to LogCat?

Comment: Also do you have any idea how I can get that image from my phone? I can only send it via SMS, which is not working on the emulator. And I can't find it on the device. It isn't in the gallery.

Comment: "how I can get that image from my phone?" -- well, if you are getting "Error saving preview", presumably you do not have an image.

Comment: It works on API level 21, but I can't find the image nor send it.

Comment: Most likely, it is not being indexed by the `MediaStore`. Use the Device File Explorer on Android Studio, or `adb shell`, to try to find it.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to log in to email before I can send it via email. Makes sense. I can still not use it on API 26, but that shouln't be a problem because I only have to take it once.

Comment: Ok it's still a problem because the button looks a lot different on API level 21

Comment: I solved it by granting the storage permission... makes sense.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I solved my problem by granting the Storage Permission manually for the Widget Preview app in the app settings.
The default Widget Preview app on the emulator crashes when trying to send a mail, but there is a newer version on the Playstore that works.

Comment: Brilliant! You saved me a looot of time!

Comment: An easy way to pull the image: open the Device File Explorer in Android Studio, find the image (in my case it was in sdcard/Download), right click and save as.